# Disable sudo password for specific user login

Tags: bash, sudo

I have a bash script that executes some PostgreSQL as

```sh
sudo -i -u postgres psql <<EOF > /dev/null
--SQL CODE
EOF
```

The sudo asks me for a password for the current user and I'd like to disable that. I don't want to provide a password inside the script through sudo -S. I know I can disable the password for sudo using `visudo`, however I need to specify the command for which to disable it (I don't want to disable it globally). How do I disable the sudo password for `sudo -i -u postgres` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably like a line in the sudoers file as follows:

```
script_user ALL = (postgres) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/psql
```

The individual items in the line are as follows:

- `script_user`: the (standard) user which uses the bash script (i.e., your user account)
- `ALL`: special variable, here at the position where it indicates all hosts. You could try and limit this to e.g. `localhost` if you want
- `(postgres)`: user to run the command(s) as. That is, the user specified by the `-u` option
- `NOPASSWD:` special variable indicating that the following command does not require a password (for this combination of user, sudo user and host, of course)
- `/usr/bin/psql`: the specific command allowed. This could also be a comma-separated lists of commands, or `ALL`. (Obviously the path may be different on your machine.)

Related questions and answers on StackOverflow are a bit scattered and don't appear to fully answer your specific question, but I've come across an [overall nice write-up on this topic](http://toroid.org/sudoers-syntax) by Abhijit Menon-Sen, which I found clearer to read than the various man pages on sudo & friends.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the answer and the reference.